# Python pandas - what is the proper way to NaN all zeros before first non-zero value in multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` with columns `date`, `a`, `b` and an `id`. The `id` is grouping and the `date` values repeat when going to a new `id`. In column `a` and `b` I want to replace 0 with `nan` *before* first non-zero value within each `id`. So with the following data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-03-01', '2019-04-01', '2019-05-01']*3,
    'id': [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
    'a': [0,0,10,40,20,0,0,0,50,90,0,0,0,0,0],
    'b': [0,0,0,123,345,0,0,555,0,666,0,0,0,0,30]
})

          date  id   a    b
0   2019-01-01   0   0    0
1   2019-02-01   0   0    0
2   2019-03-01   0  10    0
3   2019-04-01   0  40  123
4   2019-05-01   0  20  345
5   2019-01-01   1   0    0
6   2019-02-01   1   0    0
7   2019-03-01   1   0  555
8   2019-04-01   1  50    0
9   2019-05-01   1  90  666
10  2019-01-01   2   0    0
11  2019-02-01   2   0    0
12  2019-03-01   2   0    0
13  2019-04-01   2   0    0
14  2019-05-01   2   0   30
```

The output should be

```
          date  id     a      b
0   2019-01-01   0   NaN    NaN
1   2019-02-01   0   NaN    NaN
2   2019-03-01   0  10.0    NaN
3   2019-04-01   0  40.0  123.0
4   2019-05-01   0  20.0  345.0
5   2019-01-01   1   NaN    NaN
6   2019-02-01   1   NaN    NaN
7   2019-03-01   1   NaN  555.0
8   2019-04-01   1  50.0    0.0
9   2019-05-01   1  90.0  666.0
10  2019-01-01   2   0.0    NaN
11  2019-02-01   2   0.0    NaN
12  2019-03-01   2   0.0    NaN
13  2019-04-01   2   0.0    NaN
14  2019-05-01   2   0.0   30.0
```

Observe that if all values for a given `id` within a column are zeros, then keep the zeroes.

My current solution is 2 `for`-loops: one for the columns and one for `groupby` objects on `id`; a solution where I would believe there are rooms for improvement. Any hints/help would be very much appreciated.

```
for col in ['a', 'b']:
    for i, grp in df.groupby('id'):
        min_idx = grp.index.min()
        non_z_idx = grp[grp[col] > 0].index.min()

        if not np.isnan(non_z_idx):
            df.loc[min_idx:non_z_idx - 1, col] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 2 masks with [cummax](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html) and [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) then `df.where`

```
m1 = df[['a','b']].ne(0).groupby(df.id).cummax() #false until > 0 for grp
m2 = df[['a','b']].eq(0).groupby(df.id).transform('all') #true if never > 0 for grp

df[['a','b']] = df[['a','b']].where(m1 | m2)

Out[88]:
          date  id     a      b
0   2019-01-01   0   NaN    NaN
1   2019-02-01   0   NaN    NaN
2   2019-03-01   0  10.0    NaN
3   2019-04-01   0  40.0  123.0
4   2019-05-01   0  20.0  345.0
5   2019-01-01   1   NaN    NaN
6   2019-02-01   1   NaN    NaN
7   2019-03-01   1   NaN  555.0
8   2019-04-01   1  50.0    0.0
9   2019-05-01   1  90.0  666.0
10  2019-01-01   2   0.0    NaN
11  2019-02-01   2   0.0    NaN
12  2019-03-01   2   0.0    NaN
13  2019-04-01   2   0.0    NaN
14  2019-05-01   2   0.0   30.0
```

If you don't want 2 groupby's, you may use one groupby with `apply`

```
m = df[['a','b']].ne(0).groupby(df.id).apply(lambda x: x.cummax() | ~x.any())
df[['a','b']] = df[['a','b']].where(m)
```

Comment: This clearly works, but it took me a LONG time with trial and error in repl to grok...